# It always says Correct! What did I do wrong?

Tags: php

```
$number1 = mt_rand(1,9);
$number2 = mt_rand(1,9);

$total = $number1 * $number2;

echo "<form method='post'>";
echo $number1 . " x " . $number2 . " = <input type='number' name='num1' required /><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit!' name='done'>";
echo "</form>";

if (isset($_POST['done'])) { 
    if (isset($_POST['num1']) == $total) {
        echo "Correct!";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong!";
    } 
 }
```

It always says Correct! And I dont know why ( im a beginner ), I just want to check if num1 is equal to $total

Comment: Do you know that it refreshes `$total` every time you submit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many problems in your code :

1. you must first check if the post is submit then if its wrong  type the form

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['done'])) {
       //your code 
   }
   else {
       //your form
   }
   ```
2. save `$total` in session to reuse it when the form submit, in your case $total have different value every time
3. `isset()` return true or false you can't comparison true or false with integer value if you want to use isset your code must be like this:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['num1']) && $_POST['num1'] == $total) {
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone :D I got it, and I understand the problem now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing isset($var) to $total. They're both truthy so the condition is always true as long as 'num1' is defined in your POST data.

Maybe you should do something like :

```
isset($_POST['num1']) && $_POST['num1'] == $total
```

You should also probably cast 'num1' to a number

Comment: This is correct, note that if OP implements this change the code shall always return _Wrong!_ because `$total` changes when the form is submitted (value mismatch between `$_POST` and `$total`). For the OP: I'd recommend you use sessions to fix this.

Comment: Unless he is very lucky I guess

Comment: It's not strictly needed to typecast it to a number, as PHP is not strongly typed (string `"9“ == 9` int is true, unless using strict comparison). It can produce weird results, which the original question encounters. `true == 9` is true.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Tom Udding, every time you refresh the page it calls ALL of that code again, so number1 and number2 are being randomly selected again.

Your current code has no way of saving the previous variable values. An unconventional way would be to add a hidden form field with the answer to the question, like below:

```
  <?php

 if (isset($_POST['done']) && isset($_POST['num1']))
     {
     //Get answer from form.
     $total = $_POST['answer'];

     if ($_POST['num1'] == $total)
         {
         echo "Correct!";
         } 
         else
         {
         echo "Wrong!";
         }
     }
 $number1 = mt_rand(1, 9);
 $number2 = mt_rand(1, 9);

 $total = $number1 * $number2;

 echo "<form method='post'>";
 echo $number1 . " x " . $number2 . " = <input type='number' name='num1' required /><br>";

//Added hidden form with answer.
 echo "<input type='number' hidden name='answer' value='$total' />";
 echo "<input type='submit' value='submit!' name='done'>";
 echo "</form>";
?>
```

**HOWEVER...**

In a realistic rich web application, you wouldn't put your answer in your form for users to see, this is where you can use [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to track your user's information as they traverse (or in your case refresh) your page.

So a more practical answer to your question would be the following:

```
<?php

 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['done']) && isset($_POST['num1']))
     {
     $answer = $_SESSION['answer'];

     if ($_POST['num1'] == $answer)
         {
         echo "Correct!";
         } else
         {
         echo "Wrong!";
         }
     }
 $number1 = mt_rand(1, 9);
 $number2 = mt_rand(1, 9);

 $total = $number1 * $number2;
 $_SESSION['answer'] = $total;

 echo "<form method='post'>";
 echo $number1 . " x " . $number2 . " = <input type='number' name='num1' required /><br>";
 echo "<input type='number' hidden name='answer' value='$total' />";
 echo "<input type='submit' value='submit!' name='done'>";
 echo "</form>";
?>
```